# This or That Equals Shorthand

Tags: javascript, logic

Is there a more elegant way to write:

```
if((this=='condition')||(that=='condition')){break}
```

Am I missing a logical symbol here?

Comment: Short answer: no. The parentheses are unnecessary, and you could store `'condition'` in a variable, but the conditional logic is required. You could create a function that would do something like this, but there's no operator that will do it for you.

Comment: More terse: `if ( this=='condition' || that=='condition' ) break;`

Comment: `if(this=='condition'||that=='condition'){break}` -This also works...

Comment: Oh, I see.  You want to `union` multiple variables to a single value.

Comment: perhaps you can rewrite the `if` statement to be part of your `switch case:`; not sure of that would be elegant in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do from the question, but if you want to do this:

```
if( a == 'qwerty' || b == 'qwerty' ) break;
```

Then firstly, **switch to `===`**. The double `==` is a slower algorithm which has to allow for different types, whereas the `===` can fail faster. When all the values are strings the performance is the same, but when some of the values are `false` or `null` or `undefined`, `==` is much slower, as [this jsperf shows](http://jsperf.com/doublevtripleequals). It also (more importantly) exposes you to annoying bugs like: `"" == false` gives `true`, but `"" == null` gives `false`. Finally `===` is explicit both to the interpreter and anyone reading the code that you expect matching types here.

If, on the other hand you were trying to do this:

```
if( a == 'someValue' || a == 'someOtherValue' ) break;
```

Then for a large number of unchanging values, it could be quicker to make a dictionary/object and look up things in that. For example, when you are matching against a set of 1000 values, it is something like 45x quicker than doing explicit comparisons or indexOf with a list, as [this jsperf shows](http://jsperf.com/lookupvalueamongmany).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are asking is no simpler than what you wrote.  However, this becomes a chore writing `'condition'` if you have to compare it against 8 million values.  Therefore, I propose the following:

```
if ( ['this', 'that', 'there'].indexOf('condition') != -1 ) break;
```

Also, you could use `some` if you want more control...

```
if ( ['this', 'that', ...].some(function(arg) {
    return arg == 'condition';
}) ) { 
    break;
}
```

This way, you could take an array of a thousand elements and compare them with the `some` method.

Another way is to write a union function:

```
function union() {
    for ( var i=0; i<arguments.length-1; i++ ) {
        if ( arguments[i] === arguments[arguments.length-1] ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
if ( union(this, that, etc..., comparator) ) { break; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove some parentheses :

```
if (this=='condition'||that=='condition') break;
```